# Is there a way to compare 2 ref structs by reference?

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

Recently I was wandering if it's possible to compare structs by reference. As reading a struct variable creates a copy of that variable, comparing standard structs by reference seems impossible. However using C# 7 `ref`s would make more sense.

I defined 4 variables

```
MyStruct foo = new MyStruct(){SomeInt = 1};
ref MyStruct refFoo = ref foo;

MyStruct bar = new MyStruct() { SomeInt = 2 };
ref MyStruct refBar = ref foo;
```

## Given MyStruct is a standard struct

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this: `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(refFoo, refBar);`, I get **warning** saying that the value is always false, since I'm passing value types.

## If I use C# 7 `ref struct` instead

```
ref struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this: `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(refFoo, refBar);`, I get a **compilation error** saying that `MyStruct` is not assignable to parameter type `object`. Same thing if I try: `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(foo, bar);`

## The last case is when `MyStruct` is `ref struct`, but `refFoo` and `refBar` variables are declared without `ref`. (I get the same error as in the 2nd case)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyStruct foo = new MyStruct(){SomeInt = 1};
    MyStruct refFoo = foo;

    MyStruct bar = new MyStruct() { SomeInt = 2 };
    MyStruct refBar = foo;

    var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(refFoo, refBar);

}

ref struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

- So, is there some sneaky way to compare structs by reference?
- Bonus question: Why only the 2nd and 3rd examples give me a compilation
  error?

Comment: *Why only the 2nd example gives me a compilation error?* Because `ref struct` can not be boxed.

Comment: @PetSerAl No idea. That's partially what I'm asking :)

Comment: The way I understand it, ref structs are just required to be on the stack, you can't obtain a reference to it the same way you can't obtain a reference to a stack allocated array. The difference here is that the compiler is not exposing the pointers that exist behind the scenes.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks, that would explain the 'bouns question'.

Comment: [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.AreSame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.aresame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(refFoo, refBar);`, I get warning saying that the value is always false, since I'm passing value types

Each of the values will boxed so the result is always false.

> `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(refFoo, refBar);`, I get a compilation error saying that MyStruct is not assignable to parameter type object. Same thing if I try: `var comparison1 = ReferenceEquals(foo, bar);`

`ref` can't be boxed or unboxed (Like @PetSerAl wrote).

> The last case is when MyStruct is ref struct, but refFoo and refBar variables are declared without ref. (I get the same error as in the 2nd case)

Same as above.

> Bonus question: Why only the 2nd and 3rd examples give me a compilation error?

I'm sure now you understand.

> So, is there some sneaky way to compare structs by reference?

If you mean comparing addresses, here are some examples:

```
class Program
{
    struct Struct { public int Value { get; set; } }
    ref struct RefStruct { public int Value { get; set; } }

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var @struct = new Struct { Value = 5 };
        var struct2 = @struct;
        ref Struct struct3 = ref @struct;
        Struct* p = &@struct;
        Struct* p2 = &struct2;
        Console.WriteLine($"struct  address is: {(int)p} struct  value is {p->Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"struct2 address is: {(int)p2} struct2 value is {p2->Value}");
        fixed (Struct* p3 = &struct3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"struct3 address is: {(int)p3} struct3 value is {p3->Value}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"struct and struct2 Unsafe.AreSame? {Unsafe.AreSame(ref @struct, ref struct2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"struct and struct3 Unsafe.AreSame? {Unsafe.AreSame(ref @struct, ref struct3)}");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var structAsPointer = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref @struct);
        var struct2AsPointer = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref struct2);
        var struct3AsPointer = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref struct3);
        Console.WriteLine($"struct AsPointer and struct2 AsPointer are same? {structAsPointer == struct2AsPointer}");
        Console.WriteLine($"struct AsPointer and struct3 AsPointer are same? {structAsPointer == struct3AsPointer}");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var refStruct = new RefStruct { Value = 7 };
        var refStruct2 = refStruct;
        RefStruct* p4 = &refStruct;
        RefStruct* p5 = &refStruct2;
        Console.WriteLine($"refStruct  address is: {(int)p4}, refStruct  value is: {p4->Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"refStruct2 address is: {(int)p5}, refStruct value is: {p5->Value}");

        ref RefStruct refStruct3 = ref refStruct;
        fixed (RefStruct* p6 = &refStruct3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"refStruct3 address is: {(int)p6}, refStruct3 value is: {p6->Value}");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"refStruct and refStruct2 are same? {&refStruct == &refStruct2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"refStruct and refStruct3 are same? {&refStruct == p6}");
        }
    }
}
```